# javascript getElementById style color not working with non-web-palette color

Tags: coding-style, colors, getelementbyid

I need to display an e-mail address on a page, and I have a function that builds an e-mail address from chunks that spambots hopefully won't recognize (this part works fine).  I use innerHTML to populate a span with the e-mail address once the javascript function concatenates all of the chunks.

I'm trying to color the text of the link after it has been populated into the span.  Both of these work:

document.getElementById('span_ID').style.color = 'red';

document.getElementById('span_ID').style.color = '#FF0000';

...but this doesn't:

document.getElementById('span_ID').style.color = '#2200c1';

It's a red color that's part of the site style & can't be changed, and using the default blue for the link is not an option either.  I already found a few other people asking the same question, but their solutions didn't work for me.  I also tried putting  in the function that concatenates the string, which also didn't work.

So what's up here?

Comment: It works for me.. I think you have the wrong hex value for your color. http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/c7uJE/ `#2200c1` is a blueish color not redish.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will make a difference but have you tried capitalising the c in '#2200c1'? I don't think that would be a problem but you might as well try!

Comment: Thanks - tried that, didn't work.

BTW, in order to make sure the page isn't cached & the function is executing with the new code that I'm trying, I have alert('1'); as the first line of the function that changes the color and I manually increment it each time I try something new.  Just FWIW...